# Laravel - User profile pages

Tags: laravel

In my app I have a users table and a profiles table. When a user goes to their dashboard, they should be able to click a link to view their profile page. Here's the link:

`<a href="{{ route('profiles.show',$profiles->id)}}">link to your profile page</a>`

However, I am getting the error: **Route [profiles.show] not defined.**

I'm a novice and am not clear on how to link a signed up user with his/her profile page. All users should have a profile page on sign up.

I'd appreciate some guidance! Here is what I have so far:

---

**The link to profile page**

`<a href="{{ route('profiles.show',$profiles->id)}}">link to your profile page</a>`

**ProfilesController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Profile;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfilesController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        $profile = Profile::find($id);
        return view('profiles.show', compact('profile'));
    }
}
```

**Profile.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

**routes/web.php**

`Route::get('pages/profiles', 'ProfilesController@show');`

**profiles.blade.php**

*This is just a very simple page for now.*

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>{{ $user->user_id }}</h1>

    <p>{{ $user->about_me }}</p>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**Solution**

I found an easy solution and I wanted to post it here to help others who might be struggling with creating a user profile page. The below assumes you already have a users table in your database and now you want to create a profiles table and connect user ID to their profile page.
Adding Laravel User Profiles

This is [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAVvOW64c0g) which help me.

**Create table**

```
php artisan make:migration create_profiles_table
```

This creates a migration file:

```
2019_09_22_213316_create_profiles_table
```

**Open migration file and add extra columns you need:**

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->string('about_me')->nullable();
```

**Migrate these to database**

```
php artisan migrate
```

**Now we have our database sorted, we need to create a controller to control how our php functions.**

```
ProfilesController.php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class ProfilesController extends Controller
{
    public function show($user_id)
    {
        $user = User::find(1);
        $user_profile = Profile::info($user_id)->first();
        return view('profiles.show', compact('profile', 'user'));
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Profile');
    }
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('dashboard/profile', 'ProfilesController@show');
```

**Profile.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

**Add this to User.php**

```
public function profile()
{
return $this->hasOne('Profile');
}
```

**profile.blade.php**

Create any design you want. If you want to pull in users name, include `{{ Auth::user()->name }}`

Answer (score 0):

Your route is wrong, take a look at [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#named-routes). If you don't use [`Route::resource()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers), you have to manually name your routes and specify when you are expecting a parameter (in this case the profile ID).

```php
Route::get('pages/profiles/{id}', 'ProfilesController@show')->name('profiles.show');
```

```php
<a href="{{ route('profiles.show', $profile)}}">link to your profile page</a>
```

[Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-model-binding) is probably the way to go in this case.

```php
Route::get('pages/profiles/{profile}', 'ProfilesController@show')->name('profiles.show');
```

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Profile;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfilesController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Profile $profile)
    {
        return view('profiles.show', compact('profile'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @azeós, I updated using your exact code but still get 'Undefined variable: profiles'

Comment: in blade file you use   <body>
    <h1>{{ $profile->user_id }}</h1>

    <p>{{ $profile->about_me }}</p>
</body>  i chnage my answer

Comment: Could someone please tell me how to I define a variable? I've Googled it and been on Laravel website but nothing is clear. Whatever I've tried, I get the same error "undefined variable".

Comment: @PHP75DJ the variable is `$profile`, singular. But I'm confused, if you are inside the `show()` method, why will you have a link to the profile you already are?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Route::get('pages/profiles/{id}', 'ProfilesController@show')->name('profiles.show');
```

Because in link you use a name route but in web.php there is no name route called profiles.show.

so it's show error.And In Route You Need To pass the ID.

Comment: That didn't work, ```Undefined variable: profiles ```

Answer (score 0):

At Blade File :

```
<a href="{{ route('profiles.show',$profiles->id)}}">link to your profile page</a>
```

Change Route Style like below :

```
Route::get('pages/profiles/{id}', 'ProfilesController@show')->name('profiles.show');
```

At Profile Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

In Profiles.blade.php

```
<body>
  <h1>{{ $profile->id }}</h1>

   <p>{{ $profile->about_me }}</p>
</body>
```

You Passed User information through "profile" parameter. So you have to write this name in blade file.

## Note Route Function won't work if you don't mentioned any name for this Route name. Either you have to use URL.